# How to get the information of a file when it is of a type that was restricted on the Dragger component in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a Dragger component that looks like this

```js
const { Dragger } = Upload

<Dragger
  {...{
    onChange: (file) => {
      console.log({ file });
    },
    multiple: false,
    onRemove,
    beforeUpload,
    fileList: EMPTY_ARRAY,
    accept: fileTypeRestriction,
  }}>
  <p className="ant-upload-hint">Drag file here</p>
  <p className="ant-upload-hint">or</p>
  <Spacer y="md" />
  <Button>Select file</Button>
</Dragger>
```

When a user drags a file that is not accepted, I do not have a way of getting feedback that the file was rejected. I need to be able to tell a user that the file was rejected because of the file type, but I don't see a way of doing this in the `Dragger` component.

`beforeUpload` & `onChange` only returns if it is of an accepted filetype. Is there any other way to capture the drag event?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example

Following code checks the file type before upload and shows error when user drags and drops a file which is of incorrect type

```js
beforeUpload: (file) => {
  const isPNG = file.type === 'image/png';
  if (!isPNG) {
    message.error(`${file.name} is not a png file`);
  }
  return isPNG || Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
},
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload } from 'antd';

const { Dragger } = Upload;
const props = {
  name: 'file',
  multiple: true,
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',

  beforeUpload: (file) => {
    const isPNG = file.type === 'image/png';
    if (!isPNG) {
      message.error(`${file.name} is not a png file`);
    }
    return isPNG || Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
  },

  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;

    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }

    if (status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },

  onDrop(e) {
    console.log('Dropped files', e.dataTransfer.files);
  },
};

const App = () => (
  <Dragger {...props}>
    <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
      <InboxOutlined />
    </p>
    <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
  </Dragger>
);

export default App;
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]